# Can not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig

Tags: magento2, cli

I get this error when i try bin/magento comand from CLI

```
An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig)
```

how can i fix or debug?

just try :

```
change php7.3 to php7.2 version
composer install
composer update
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ && rm -rf pub/static/_cache && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ && rm -rf var/cache && rm -rf generated/code
    && rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/ &&  rm -rf generated/metadata
```

Comment: I just tried to downgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.3.4, and now I am getting this error when trying to use bin/magento. Did you figure this out?

Comment: i make an upgrade from 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 but i have this error after a composer upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I have solved upgrading magento from 2.3.5 to 2.3.5-p1
I'm not sure but i think that somethings went wrong with composer

Comment: I have a support ticket open with Magento Commerce, and they say that you cannot upgrade from 2.3.5 to 2.3.5-p1 directly, that you have to downgrade Magento to 2.3.4 first. I am currently on 2.3.5 trying to get to 2.3.5-p1 but can't seem to get past this error after downgrading. Are you saying you upgraded to 2.3.5-p1 directly from 2.3.5?

Comment: yes i do it wich is the problem you have found?

Comment: I haven't tried to go directly to 2.3.5 from 2.3.5-p1 yet, only because support said I couldn't. I may try if my second attempt at downgrading doesn't work though.